# Multipole expansion - different derivation leads to the dipole decreasing in $r^{-2}$ and $r^{-3}$

Tags: electrostatics, voltage, dipole, multipole-expansion

To prepare myself for the electrodynamics course i used Griffith, in which his derivation gives

$$V(r)=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}(\frac{1}{r}\int \rho(r')d \tau ' + \frac{1}{r^2}\int r'cos\alpha \rho(r')d\tau ' + ....)$$

Then my professor gave another derivation:

$$V(r)=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}(\frac{Q}{|\vec{\eta}|}-\frac{Q}{\vec{|\eta} + \vec{d}|})$$

Using Taylor expansion:

$$V(r)=\frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac{\vec{d} \cdot \vec{r}}{r^3}+O(\frac{|\vec{d}|}{r^3})$$

He simply concluded that without showing us the steps so i thought he made a mistake, i taylor expanded it myself and it's correct..

Now im confused, now does the dipole fall off in proportion to $r^{-2}$ or $r^{-3}$?

Comment: First of all, there is a typo. In your denominator you should have magnitudes, not vectors. Secondly, in the expression given by your Professor there is a $\vec{r}=r\hat{r}$ in the numerator.

Comment: but in griffith he also mentions $r'cos\alpha = \hat{r} \cdot r'$ which by the way i dont quite get why...

Comment: That's just the dot product formula $a \cdot b = |a| |b| \cos\theta$. Also note that you have $\frac{r}{r^3} = \frac{\hat{r}}{r^2}$ in the potential.

Comment: So they are essentially the same?